# Not refreshing main page after submit an include page

Tags: post, include, refresh

I have got a main page with a form that contains another page (include) with another form. When i post the included one, the main one refresh. How can avoid this happening?

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your code as well so that i can help you

Answer (score 0):

Using POST automatically refreshes the Page, no matter where you use it. (Main Page, included parts).

Try to use Javascript or Jquery to Update the "included" part without refreshing the Page.

Comment: what i really need is to keep some select values from main one after submitting the include one that cause the main refreshing....